# Update Query not working in classic asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic

```
update products set wcview = '1',ccview ='1' where pcprod_parentPrd = 33576 AND    pcprod_relationship like '%18493%'
```

This sql query works when I execute in  the sql client which i use to connect to the database

But same thing when i use from classic asp code, like

```
relation =  Uid // This will give me 18439 
wcview and ccview is 1 // I have tested this

query1 = "update products set wcview = " & wcView &",ccview = " & ccView &" where pcprod_parentPrd = "& pIdProduct &" AND pcprod_relationship like '%"& relation &"%'"
```

The same query is working when LIKE filter in the where clause returns only 1 row so its updating one row, but same when Like filters more than one row it is not updating from classic asp.

From the client it is not the problem

Please help..

Comment: [Parameterised Queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) that is all.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL client query you have single quotes around your insert values, in your asp version you don't

try

```
query1 = "update products set wcview = '" & wcView &"',ccview = '" & ccView &"' where pcprod_parentPrd = "& pIdProduct &" AND pcprod_relationship like '%"& relation &"%'"
```

Also, when you're debugging, it's worth putting in `Response.Write query1` on the line before the one where the query is executed.  It's very easy in classic asp to get the syntax wrong when you're using SQL with variables